# PDO insert statement not posting

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I dont get any errors, but when I refresh my database nothing seems to be going through. The connection credentials are definitely correct.

```
$query = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO direct_transfer (fname, lname, add, city, post, country, email, nummag, donate) VALUES (:fname, :lname, :add, :city, :post, :country, :email, :nummag, :donate)');
$query->execute(array(':fname'=>$fname,
 ':lname'=>$lname,
 ':add'=>$add,
 ':city'=>$city,
 ':post'=>$post,
 ':country'=>$country,
 ':email'=>$email,
 ':nummag'=>$nummag,
 ':donate'=>$donate));
```

Answer (score 4):

When you use [reserved words in mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html), you need to escape them in backticks:

```
... (fname, lname, `add`, city, post, country, email, nummag, donate) ...
```

You should also add error handling so that PDO tells you right away what is wrong.

You can tell PDO to throw exceptions by adding this after you connect to the database:

```
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

You can also set the error handling mode when you open the connection, see the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php).

Comment: What do I need to include to see errors? Sorry I am new to this.

Comment: Shouldn't this `'lname'=>$lname,` have colons also? `':lname'=>$lname,` etc.

Comment: @Fred-ii- It should, although I am pretty sure both work. It seems the question has been edited already...

Comment: @jeroen thanks! Your solution solved my problem. Will need to find a list of these reserved words in the future :)

Comment: @pwneth I just added a link.

Comment: I've never tried it myself without the colons, but worth a quick test. I only take it from what I've learned so far. @jeroen

Comment: You can find them here >>> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html @pwneth

Comment: @Fred-ii- I always use the colons as it seems the correct way to go, but I got corrected here on SO once when I claimed they were necessary :-)

Comment: I understand. I will test it though (sometime soon), with a working piece of code I have. @jeroen

Comment: I tested one of my scripts without the colons `'lname'=>$lname` , and it worked also. Thought I would let you know. @jeroen

Answer (score 1):

Without '`:`' in the array.

```
$query = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO `direct_transfer` (`fname`, `lname`, `add`, `city`, `post`, `country`, `email`, `nummag`, `donate`) VALUES (:fname, :lname, :add, :city, :post, :country, :email, :nummag, :donate)');

$query->execute(array('fname'=>$fname,
                      'lname'=>$lname,
                      'add'=>$add,
                      'city'=>$city,
                      'post'=>$post,
                      'country'=>$country,
                      'email'=>$email,
                      'nummag'=>$nummag,
                      'donate'=>$donate));
```

Comment: With or without the colons `:` it still works, so that wasn't the issue. The actual problem was the use of the [`reserved word`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) `"add"` which needed to be put inside backticks. However, your answer having all of the columns inside backticks is a good method. So, using `':fname'=>$fname` or `'fname'=>$fname` are both good. However, the colons are required for the `VALUES`. Yet, all is not lost. I did `+1` your answer, cheers.